# Angularjs displaying day old.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have following code

```
<div ng:app ng:controller="Scoper">
    In: {{v.sDt}}  <br />
    Angular: {{v.sDt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}} <br />
</div>
```

In my controller I have

```
function Scoper($scope) {
    var s = "2009-09-03T00:00:00Z";
    $scope.v = {
        Dt: Date.now(),
        sDt: s,
        DDt: Date.parse(s)
    }
}
```

When i run it, angularjs displays date one day old.

```
In: 2009-09-03T00:00:00Z
Angular: 2009-09-02 19:00:00 0500
```

Please let me know how to fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: Different timezones. Why are you surprised?

Answer (score 0):

This is a timezone issue.  Your variable `s` is in Zulu Time (aka UTC).

Your Date Parse expression is showing the date in the current date/time and ALSO showing your offset from Zulu Time.

```
<div ng:app ng:controller="Scoper">
   In: {{v.sDt}}  <br />
   Angular: {{v.sDt | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}} <br />
</div>
```

The first part of the expression: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` is saying "Show me the date in local time.

The second part of the expression `Z` is saying "Show me what my offset is from UTC.